# Angular JS - Matching models in nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### Plunkr

http://embed.plnkr.co/10dTMNIFCoqZW8jMez4R/preview

You can add a row by clicking the plus sign.

As you can see, each span will fill up any row with any value that is put into one of the fields.

How can that be when i clearly refer a specific row?

```
 <input class="rt-input" type="text" ng-model="realm.rows[row][heading].content">
```

Comment: your plunker is producing this error message: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined`, and `ng-model` doesn't match what you posted in your question.  did you link to the wrong plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that each new row is created like this:

```
var protoRow = $scope.realm.rows[0];
...
$scope.realm.rows[rowCount] = protoRow;
```

Since `$scope.realm.rows[0]` (and hence `protoRow`) is an object, it is passed by reference. So each new table row is bound to the same object in `realm.rows`.

---

You shuld create a new copy of the object, and `angular.copy()` is just the tool for the job:

```
var protoRow = $scope.realm.rows[0];
...
$scope.realm.rows[rowCount] = angular.copy(protoRow);
```

---

See, also, this **[modified, working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X0AXaneg5ufWSrVjHHdC?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your plnkr to make it work. http://plnkr.co/edit/D98tLpXEZgV63GjUTJbD?p=preview

The problem was that all your rows were referring to the same object.

So I just copy your "prototype row" with `angular.copy()`

```
var protoRow = angular.copy($scope.realm.rows[0]);
```

and

```
$scope.realm.rows[rowCount] = angular.copy(protoRow);
```